# share the encfs encrypted ".directory" via NFS

Tags: nfs, file-sharing, disk-encryption, encfs

encfs uses FUSE to mount an encrypted directory (a hidden ".directory" by convention) onto another directory specified by the user.

I want to share the encrypted ".directory" via NFS where it will be decrypted on the client (on demand).

When I try doing that the mount command succeeds and **no errors are reported** (even with "-vvv" parameter). However, **the mount on the client is always empty.** Why? How do I resolve this?

My plan is that the client will not have to keep the decrypted directory mounted at all times, thus increasing security (I hope).

The other way of sharing it, where it is decrypted on the NFS server means it will have to stay decrypted at all times (afaik).

**UPDATE**: I want to clarify that I am not mounting the decrypted directory on the NFS server and then trying to share that. I am trying to share the raw encrypted directory.

**NFS server** (192.168.1.1 fileserver)

/etc/fstab:

```
/home/.shared /export/home/.shared        none    bind 0 0
```

/etc/exports:

```
/export/home/.shared 192.168.1.10(fsid=2,rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,nohide)
```

**NFS client** (192.168.1.10)

I haved tried two approaches:
first try:

```
fileserver:/export/home/.shared /home/.shared  nfs4    noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,intr,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.10,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1      0 0
```

I have also tried:

```
fileserver:/export/home/.shared /home/.shared     nfs4    noauto,_netdev,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,intr    0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated question; I've deleted my wrong answer :-).  What you've written _looks_ correct.  Is `/export` on a separate filesystem? Out of curiousity, after `fileserver` has started, what happens if you run `exportfs -a` and then on the client `mount` the filesystem?   I wonder if you're hitting a `systemd` race condition between mounting and exporting...

Comment: @StephenHarris-thanks. I will try your suggestion and report back tomorrow. (I can't mess with the fileserver during the day while people are using it.)

Comment: Is it **common** to do what I'm trying to do (NFS share the encrypted encfs directory and then decrypt it on the client)? Or am I trying to do something really unusual?

Comment: If you want user encrypted data to be shared between machines then exporting the encrypted data is the right way to go; it's a lot more secure!  I just installed `encfs` on two of my test VMs and what you're trying to do worked just fine (CentOS 7.2; EPEL) but the small VMs had $HOME/encrypted on the root disk (small VMs; single disk volume).  FWIW, the export is `/home/sweh/encrypted *(fsid=2,rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,nohide)` and I manually just ran `sudo mount test1:/home/sweh/encrypted /home/sweh/encrypted`.

Comment: I got a change to test it. I checked all settings on the server and the clients. Then I shut all systems down, booted the server first, then booted the clients. It is working now. My problem must have been something else. Thanks for confirming that I was on the right track. I might have given up otherwise. :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris - If you want to provide an answer summarizing the right way to do this I'll accept it.

Comment: btw, I did not need the fsid parameter in /etc/exports when doing it this way. That is needed only if sharing the decrypted, mounted directory (which I'm not doing). In that case I believe it is needed because NFS can't recognize the filesystem type or ID.

Comment: Most of those flags aren't _needed_ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data stored in the encrypted directory just looks like normal files to the filesystem (just with odd names and encrypted data).  So exporting the encrypted mountpoint will work as normal.

So, on server `test1` we can create a test directory:

```
$ cd /home/sweh
$ mkdir encrypted decrypted
$ encfs ~/encrypted ~/decrypted
[...]
$ echo hello > decrypted/foo
$ ls encrypted
C-1Ky9g41JBTIYaBJC7EeiiH
```

Now we can export this.  `/etc/exports` has:

```
/home/sweh/encrypted *(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,nohide)
```

And we run `exports -a` to export it.

Now on `test2` we can mount it:

```
$ mkdir encrypted decrypted
$ sudo mount test1:/home/sweh/encrypted encrypted
$ ls encrypted
C-1Ky9g41JBTIYaBJC7EeiiH
```

And we can use this with `encfs` on the client:

```
$ encfs /home/sweh/encrypted /home/sweh/decrypted 
EncFS Password: 
$ cat decrypted/foo 
hello
```